# Can a dictionary be used to pass variables to a function?

Tags: python

I have a class with an init function that needs ~20 variables passed to it. Instantiations of the class are rather ugly:

```
some_var = MyClass(param1=mydict('param1')
                   param2=mydict('param2')
                   param3=mydict('param3')
                   ...
                   param20=mydict('param20')
```

I keep all of those parameters in a dictionary for easy handling already. Not all parameters are necessary so I don't want the class to accept only a dictionary object I don't think.

I'm wondering if I there's a nice trick to clean this up by specifying that the parameters to **init** are to be taken from the dictionary?

I'm just looking for tips and tricks on tidying this up a little. I have quite a few long/ugly instantiations of this class.

Comment: yes. Use `MyClass(**mydict)` for key-word argument unpacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use keyword argument expansion:

```
some_var = MyClass(**mydict)
```

Comment: Sounds dangerous...

Comment: Why would that be dangerous? Isnt it part of the language to unpack?

Comment: @DavidBern sarcasm :)

Comment: aaah. Im like Dr Sheldon Cooper. Dont understand sarcasm. Well, in that case, it was a funny remark

Comment: I was making a joke about the use of "keyword explosion". I believe the author of this answer meant *expansion*.

Comment: There are like 20 variables, it does feel like an explosion. This is a new feature for me, so it's likely I know enough to be dangerous now. It certainly looks as pretty as I was hoping for, but then again so do mushroom clouds.

Comment: Can I request a clarification on a more serious note? What if one parameter is missing from the dictionary? Does `MyClass(param21=True, **mydict)` work? What if I just want to override one parameter that *is* in the dictionary, does this work: `MyClass(param1=False, **mydict)`. What I mean to ask is whether I can have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: That was easy enough to test. Adding parameters that don't exist in the dictionary works fine, but overriding dictionary parameters causes a "multiple values for keyword" exception. Also having extraneous values in the dictionary that aren't parameters of the function causes an exception. I can have my cake, eat it, but no frosting!